# имена переменных в elf файле

Tags: linux, c, elf

Я разобрался с elf заголовком, но не полностью. В elf заголовке есть указатели на секции и т.д. Но я не пойму где хранятся указатели на переменные. Я пишу дизассемблер и мне бы хотелось ещё иметь такую опцию, как видеть имена переменных в выводе. Пока что видно только адреса. Где и как обращаться к таким названиям, чтобы можно было их ставить взамен адресу?

Answer (score 1):

Имена переменных и функций не сохраняются в скомпилированных бинарниках.

Для того чтобы сопоставить адреса названиям используется отладочная информация, которая может быть вкомпилена в бинарь, а может располагаться в отдельном файле.

Еще имена сохраняются у экспортируемых символов, чтобы к ним можно было обратиться из другого модуля.

Если хотите извлекать имена локальных переменных и внутренних функций, то путь только один - из отладочной информации. Гуглите библиотеку для работы с DWARF. Чтобы извлечь имена экспортов, можно воспользоваться утилитой `nm` или произвести аналогичные действия с помощью какой-нибудь `libelf`.

Comment: не совсем верно, в nix-мире все символы (и функции, и глобальные переменные) со внешней линковкой по-умолчанию являются видимыми («экспортируемыми» в терминологии MS), если иное явно не задано в опциях компилятора.

Comment: Так я же программирую хочу сделать. Мне нужен способ как добраться до этих переменных. Например если я в nasm ассемблере скомпилирую программу, то имена переменных запишутся в бинарик. Я пишу дизассемблер и мне надо в каких то случаях писать вместо адреса имя переменной.

Comment: @xverizex: В какой такой "бинарик" у вас запишутся имена переменных в nasm? Где вы такое видели? Что такое "бинарик" в данном случае?

Comment: @AnT ну я пишу на ассемблере программу. С помощью hexdump смотрю строки и там есть имена переменных, которые я указывал в секции данных. Бинарик, это бинарный файл, то есть программа.

Comment: @xverizex: Так а что показывает `readelf -s` в том случае, о которым вы говорите в вопросе? По-видимому к результату работы nasm в вашем случае никто не применял `strip`, поэтому вы видите там имена внешних переменных. А в том случае, о котором вы говорите в вопросе, результат был stripped.

Comment: @arrowd: По умолчанию внешние символы как раз таки обычно сохраняются в заголовках скомпилированных ELF-executables. Из оттуда можно удалить, но это нужно специально запрашивать/делать.

Comment: Я, вроде, все так и написал. Не понимаю чего вы тут спорите. @xverizex, см. мой ответ. Либо парсите вывод `readelf`/`nm`/еще чего-то, либо ищете библиотеку, которая позволяет это сделать. Подозреваю, что библиотека называется `libelf`.